# Create a linked list function without creating another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am working on some practice exercises with linked lists and I got stuck with one function.

My program should create a `Node class`, take user input with `create()` function (number n and then takes in n number of elements), and has a function `printLinkedList(p)` to print it out. So far this works well but then I should create another function where I am going to be deleting the max element (if it occurs more than once, delete the first occurrence).

I found a function `findMaxElement(p)` that looks for the max, however, it doesn't work along my code (for example I get `AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'head'` error)

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x = None):
        self.data = x            
        self.next = None         

def create():
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        return None
    s = input().split()
    p = Node(int(s[0]))
    k = p
    for i in range(1, n):
        t = Node(int(s[i]))
        k.next = t
        k = t
    return p

def printLinkedList(p):
    if p == None:
        print('Empty')
        return
    s = p
    while s != None:
        print(s.data, end = " ")
        s = s.next
    print()

def findMaxElement(p):
    current = p.head    
    #Initializing max to initial node info    
    maximum = p.head.data    
    if(p.head == None):    
       print("List is empty")
    else:    
        while(True):    
            #If current node's info is greater than max    
            #Then replace value of max with current node's info    
            if(maximum < current.info):    
                maximum = current.info    
            current= current.next  
            if(current == p.head):    
                break
    return "Maximum value node in the list: "+ str(maximum) 

#Driver code
a = create()
printLinkedList(a)
```

Input:

```py
6
1 7 4 2 6 7
```

Expected result:

```py
1 7 4 2 6 7
1 4 2 6 7
```

Comment: Hard to understand your code with all these single char variable names. What are you feeding to your `findMaxElement` function? You have to give it the list itself as a paramter, not the `Node` object.

Comment: Yeah, why do you expect `p.head` to work? You can't expect just copying another algorithm that was written to work with another class definition to work with yours. Of course it won't just work (note, it seems to assume you actually wrote a linked-list class, which manages the nodes internally, the way you should normally do this anyhow).

Comment: @po.pe I want to add `findMaxElement(a)` to the driver code as I can't create lists

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am aware of all of that, that is why I am trying to find help here because I would need to change it or at least get an advice on how to create this function without an additional class

Comment: `p.head` probably origins from pandas, but you cannot just use it with your list. Try to clean up your code and don't reuse single char variable names.

Comment: @po.pe unlikely, its a function written to work with a typical linked-list implementation

Comment: Sounds reasonable :)
@Yira, do you understand your code? I got the impression that these are copied snippets from different other projects.

Comment: I agree with @po.pe last comment, namely _I got the impression that these are copied snippets from different other projects._ Not only does it look like a bunch of copy/pasted snippets, it's an extremely unpythonic style. I'm voting to close this, as it is completely unclear what's going on.

Comment: Also, do note that variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC I wrote everything except `findMaxElement(p)` also why changing to lower case style with underscores?

Comment: @Yira Python style convention, see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

You could just define a `findMaxElement()` that traverses the linked-list in the same way that the `printLinkedList()` function is doing it (and finds the maximum value while doing so):

```
def findMaxElement(p):
    if p == None:
        return 'Empty List!'
    current = p
    maximum = p.data
    while current != None:  # Not end of list.
        if current.data > maximum:
            maximum = current.data
        current = current.next
    return "Maximum value node in the list: " + str(maximum)
```